# Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, in wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php on line 287

Tags: wordpress, function

I am creating my first WordPress theme for personal use, when I added main function in functions.php, website showing an warning on top.

**Warning: call_user_func_array()** expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'myfirsttheme_setup ' not found or invalid function name in G:\wamp64\www\mysite\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php on line **287**.

Should I define myfirsttheme_setup function first? If yes, then how?

**My code is here:**

```
<?php
/**
 * @package myfirsttheme
 * @since myfirsttheme
*/

if ( ! function_exists( 'myfirsttheme_setup' ) ) :
/**
 * support post thumbnails.
*/

function myfirsttheme_setup() {
    add_theme_support( 'custom-header' );
    add_theme_support('menus');
    add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
    add_theme_support( 'automatic-feed-links' );
    add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );
    add_theme_support( 'customize-selective-refresh-widgets' );
}
endif; // myfirsttheme_setup
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'myfirsttheme_setup' );
```

Comment: Hi Mukesh, can I suggest that when putting up a question that you show that you've read the existing documentation. I'm sure you have - but its a good idea to take time out to show that you have by providing a couple of links.

In this case the answer to your question is here, in the WordPress themes documentation:

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/theme-functions/#theme-setup

Answer (score 2):

The code you entered is correct. `myfirsttheme_setup` just needs to be defined before the `after_setup_theme` action hook is executed. It does not need to be defined when you add the hook. The action hook will just store the string in $wp_filter global and then call call_user_func_array at execution of the hook. Your issue must be somewhere else. I would search for `myfirsttheme_setup` throughout your entire install. You have to be trying to hook to it before it's defined or changing `myfirsttheme_setup` to not be callable in another place.

You do always have the option of making it an anonymous function as well.

```php
add_action('after_setup_theme', function () {
    add_theme_support('custom-header');
    add_theme_support('menus');
    add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
    add_theme_support('automatic-feed-links');
    add_theme_support('title-tag');
    add_theme_support('customize-selective-refresh-widgets');
});
```